# what pins are attached to ethernet shield SD card?

Tags: shields, ethernet

I have ARDUINO ETH SHIELD 06 - Rev 03. https://www.adafruit.com/product/201
what pins are attached to Ethernet shield SD card?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino communicates with both the W5100 and SD card using the SPI bus (through the ICSP header). This is on digital pins 10, 11, 12, and 13 on the Uno and pins 50, 51, and 52 on the Mega. On both boards, pin 10 is used to select the W5100 and pin 4 for the SD card.